# Rate Facebook Page with API from Phone possible?

Tags: android, ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Does somebody know if it is possible to rate (1 to 5 Stars + comment) a Facebook page / place via the Facebook API from an Android/iOS App?

I find nothing corresponding in the documentation but I really can not imagine that this should not be possible.

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't knew the right term: What I've meant was to give a `review` for a Facebook page and as mentioned in the documentation:

> You cannot create reviews using the API.

damn. If somebody knows a workaround I would appreciate if he would also answer the question or comment on this.